# Coefficients of Poincare series

Tags: analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $\Gamma=SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$ and $\Gamma_\infty$ the subgroup generated by $T(z)=z+1$  and $$P^{k}_m(z)=\sum_{\gamma\in \Gamma_\infty\setminus \Gamma}\gamma'(z)^{-k/2}\exp(2i\pi m \gamma(z))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_m^{k}(n)q^n$$ the $m$-th Poincare series of weight $k$ with Fourier coefficients $ c_m^k(n)$, how to prove that $$c_m^k(n)=m^{1-k}\sum_{d|(m,n)}d^{k-1}c^k_1(\frac{nm}{d^2})$$

Edit:

The original question is already answered. The following is the reference I have.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usefulness of $P_m^k$ is its behavior with respect to the Petersson inner product, for $f\in S_k(\Gamma)$ $$\langle f,P_m^k \rangle =\int_{\Gamma \setminus \Bbb{H}} f(z)\overline{P_m^k(z)}y^{k-2}dxdy=\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 f(z) \exp(2i \pi m \overline{z})y^{k-2}dxdy$$ $$= \int_0^\infty e^{-4\pi m y} a_m(f) y^{k-2}dy =a_m(f) (4\pi m)^{1-k}\Gamma(k-1)$$
thus with $(f_j)$ the basis of eigenforms of $S_k(\Gamma)$  (because the Hecke operators are normal the  $f_j$ are orthogonal for the Petersson inner product) $$P_m^k(z) = \sum_j \frac{\langle f,P_m^k\rangle}{\langle f,f\rangle}f_j(z)=\sum_j \frac{a_m(f_j) (4\pi m)^{1-k}\Gamma(k-1)}{\langle f_j,f_j\rangle} f_j(z)$$

Their coefficients satisfy $$a_n(f_j)a_m(f_j) = m^{1-k}\sum_{d|(m,n)}d^{k-1}a_{\frac{nm}{d^2}}(f_j)$$
summing the latter over $j$ you get your result which is in condensed form 
$$T_n P_m^k =m^{1-k}\sum_{d|(m,n)}d^{k-1}  P_{nm/d^2}^k$$

Comment: In Iwaniec's "Topics in classical automorphic forms", it says that this result can be seen by considering the action of $T(n)$ on $P^k_1$, i.e, $T(n)P_1=n^{k-1}P_n$, without using the inner product. Could you explain how this works? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know, $\sum_{ad=n,b\bmod d} \exp(2i\pi  \frac{az+b}{d})$ simplifies but it is not obvious to me how to make it appear

Comment: The method of your book is quite the same as my answer except they conclude directly from that $<.,.>$ is non-degenerate without needing the eigenforms